# Undefined variable when using super gloable variable $_GLOBALS

Tags: php

I'm using super gloabl $_GLOBALS variable, but my script doesn't work for me.

```
        <?php
        $x = 75;
        $y = 25;
        function addition(){
            $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
        }
        echo $z;
        ?>
```

When I run above script, I encounter Notice:

> Undefined variable: z

error. What is wrong with my script?

Comment: Probably you will need to declare global within the function scope. eg `global $x, $y;`.

Comment: reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following code:

```
<?php 
    $x = 75;
    $y = 25; 

    function addition() {
    $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
    }

    addition();
    echo $z;
    ?>
```

You have to call the function after that you can get the variable.

Comment: It is correct. I forgot call function addition! Thank you a lot

Comment: Great..
Please do like and accept the answer if it helped you.